# What are the Risk factors in Changing sql_mode variable in mysql 5.7.12?

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1067

I am planning to upgrade our production database from mysql 5.5 to mysql 5.7.

While testing with the default sql_mode on mysql 5.7, we were getting error for zero value timestamp especially while creating tables.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/faqs-sql-modes.html#faq-mysql-what-default-mode

So I changed the default sql_mode to:
"NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"

Now the errors while creating tables are gone. Also no other query is throwing any error and currently all queries work fine.

The sql_query which was throwing the error was:

CREATE TABLE xxxxx (
    ->         `yy_id`                 int(11)       unsigned   NOT NULL default '0'   ,
    ->         `url_position`             int(11)       unsigned   NOT NULL default '0'   ,
    ->         `total_date`               date                     NOT NULL default '‎‎0000-00-00',
    ->         `terminal_cd`              tinyint(4)    unsigned   NOT NULL default '99'  ,
    ->         `click_num`                int(11)       unsigned   NOT NULL default '0'   ,
    ->         `time_stamp`               timestamp                NOT NULL               ,
    ->         PRIMARY KEY  (`yy_id`,`url_position`,`total_date`, `terminal_cd`)
    ->     ) ENGINE=InnoDB
    ->     ;

Is it okay to change the mysql default sql_mode to make it compatible with mysql 5.5 and what are the risk factors?

Comment: There are many server modes, are you asking about one in particular?

Comment: Yeah. I am concerned about :

 "NO_ZERO_IN_DATE, NO_ZERO_DATE, ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO"

Just worried, if we disable it in prod it might break some other sql.

Comment: So use your common sense.  If your previous queries had these problems, and then you turn on strict mode, then things might break.

Comment: Got it. I understood that if I turn on strict mode, things might break.
What if I turn it off?

When I "turn it off" everything works during testing.
But is it safe to turn off strict mode in mysql 5.7 when the Prod goes live.

Will any future upgrades be affected if I turn it off currently.

Comment: It's better in general to not rely on the laxities of MySQL.  For example, MySQL allows you to select non aggregate columns in a `GROUP BY` query.  Besides breaking when turning on strict mode in MySQL, such a query would likely not run in most other databases as well, making porting your code difficult.